# invoke webservice dynamically using java

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client

i want to invoke a web service based on the url and method name,when given the input parament in xml format ,i need to invoke the web service ,but i can't generate the client stub using tools like wsdl2java because the url and method name are given dynamically so these class aren't compiled.

for example,http://localhost:9090:/hello?wsdl there have a method 
string sayhello(String []names); the input param likes <arg0>john</arg0> <arg0>lucy</arg0>

it seems that i need to generate soap request in code so is there any library can help me do this?

thank you for giving any recommendation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possible and yes, you will need to generate the SOAP request yourself and also parse the reply yourself.

Some links to help with this including source code etc.:

- [SoapUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/) (complete source code of a generic SOAP client including a nice UI)
- http://anshu-manymoods.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-simple-generic-soap-test-client.html
- http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/httpclient/how-to-send-an-xml-document-to-a-remote-web-server-using-http-5.html
- http://biomoby.open-bio.org/CVS_CONTENT/moby-live/Java/docs/soapServlet.html
- http://www.soapuser.com/ngx_22jul01.html

IF JavaScript is an option you can check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/JavaScriptSOAPClient.aspx) out...

Answer (score 0):

There's [SAAJ](http://java.net/projects/saaj/) but it's pretty verbose.

If you can use Spring, [Spring-WS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/client.html) has a number of client options.

You can always just build up the XML by hand, too (and parse the returned XML).

Comment: Spring-WS is quiet convenient,but it seems that it just send a ready soap message! what I consider is how to build the soap message in my application according to given input parameters!